# How do I fix this in Firebase and CMS (Google Spreadsheet)?

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, firebase-realtime-database

I've followed [this](https://words.mxbry.com/how-i-used-google-drive-and-firebase-to-give-my-static-site-a-cms-7226e01a51b5) tutorial to use Google Sheets as a [CMS for Firebase](https://www.drivecms.xyz) Database. Everything works well but the problem is that the way the data is organized is that each time there is a new row, the default key is a numeric value (starting with 0). Here's what's happening:

My CMS setup:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

... but what I really WANT is:

[image]

I tried tweaking in the "settings" page but with no luck.